# Error en <inputs> ngModel

Tags: angular, angular8

Hola comunidad soy nuevo en angular y estoy recibiendo el siguiente error, sigo un tutorial pero a mi no me funciona esta parte.

[image: component.html]

[image: .ts]

[image: el error]

Comment: Por favor tu código debe ir como texto y no como imagen, pues no solo es difícil leerlo sino que alguien mas lo reproduzca, considera leer [ask]

Comment: Para poder usar el ngModel, tienes que ponerle un name="" a las etiquetas input donde lo estás usando.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con este HTML. Si no lo quieres copiar entero por si hay algún error que no noté, lo único que hice fue añadir `name="algo"` en los `<input>` donde tenías los `[(ngModel)]`.

```html
<form #formRegister="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegister()">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normar"> Register </h1> 
  <hr> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-auto">
      <label class="sr-only">Nombre</label> 
      <div class="input-group mb-2"> 
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-aute">
      <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"> 
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Correo electranico" required> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-aute">
      <label class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="pass" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Contraseila" required>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Registrarse       </button> 
  </div> 
</form>
```